# Force both HTTPS and HTTP with .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have several domains under the same server, but my https certificated only works for one of them.

1. I need to force https for: mydomain1.com
2. All other domains (mydomain2.com, mydomain3.com ...) must use http.

I know it must be a simple rule, but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use virtual hosts : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

**But** they require to be specified inside the server configuration (can't do it inside .htaccess)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain1.com
    DocumentRoot /www/mydomain1
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.key/server.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain2.com
    DocumentRoot /www/mydomain2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain3.com
    DocumentRoot /www/mydomain3
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't have access to it. I was trying to find a workaround using htaccess, but it seems that I will have to request this to the server admin.

Comment: All theses options are security sensitive and so are limited to server config : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslengine `Context: server config, virtual host`